# ASP.NET WebForms URLRouting - All Routes Receiving 404

Tags: iis-7, routes, http-status-code-404, asp.net-routing, webforms-routing

All routes within my ASP.NET URL Routing web application are receiving a 404. However, the actual pages that exist are showing up correctly. I'm using IIS7. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All is good now. The main issue I had was that the HttpHandler for the UrlRouting was not added to the webServer section but rather the "old" handlers section.